# Delaying cron tasks

Tags: php, cron

On my server I can run cron tasks every 5 minutes.
I have many clients (over 100).
In my cron task I send ping to every clients' subdomain to run it's own cron tasks.
I don't wait for response.

Problem is that I send ping in `foreach` loop and therefor server recieves many request in a single second.

Is there a way to delay/randomize those requests?
I knot there is a `sleep` function but it blocks server and minimum value is 1 second.

Comment: You can create the request in batch, with minimum limit of request processing.

Comment: Can You tell me more about it? Maybe link to a library? Edit found this: http://bytes.schibsted.com/php-perform-requests-in-parallel/

Comment: You can look into it, [Batch Processing in PHP] https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-batch/

Comment: you can use `usleep()` to sleep for less than a second.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're pinging different domains, so why is any server receiving many requests?

Comment: @Barmar:  there are all on my server. I'm using ping due to server timeout limit.

Comment: Why don't you just run those tasks in `cron` instead of pinging the subdomains?

Comment: @Barmar: my serwer allows only to invoke main cron file, from which I have to pass tasks further:/

Answer (score 0):

Add a `usleep` call inside the loop, to add a little pause between each ping.